# Why am I not able to attach this texture uniform to my GLSL fragment shader?

Tags: macos, opengl, glsl

In my Mac application, I define a rectangular texture based on YUV 4:2:2 data from an attached camera.  Using standard vertex and texture coordinates, I can draw this to a rectangular area on the screen without any problems.

However, I would like to use a GLSL fragment shader to process these image frames on the GPU, and am having trouble passing in the rectangular video texture as a uniform to the fragment shader.  When I attempt to do so, the texture simply reads as black.

The shader program compiles, links, and passes validation.  I am receiving the proper address for the uniform from the shader program.  Other uniforms, such as floating point values, pass in correctly and the fragment shader responds to changes in these values.  The fragment shader receives the correct texture coordinates.  I've also sprinkled my code liberally with glGetError() and seen no errors anywhere.

The vertex shader is as follows:

```
void main()
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix * gl_Vertex;

    gl_FrontColor = gl_Color;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_TextureMatrix[0] * gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

and the fragment shader is as follows:

```
uniform sampler2D videoFrame;

void main()
{
    gl_FragColor = texture2D(videoFrame, gl_TexCoord[0].st);
}
```

This should simply display the texture on my rectangular geometry.

The relevant drawing code is as follows:

```
static const GLfloat squareVertices[] = {
    -1.0f, -1.0f,
    1.0f, -1.0f,
    -1.0f,  1.0f,
    1.0f,  1.0f,
};

const GLfloat textureVertices[] = {
    0.0, videoImageSize.height,
    videoImageSize.width, videoImageSize.height,
    0.0, 0.0,
    videoImageSize.width, 0.0
};

CGLSetCurrentContext(glContext);

if(!readyToDraw)
{
    [self initGL];
    readyToDraw = YES;
}


glViewport(0, 0, (GLfloat)self.bounds.size.width, (GLfloat)self.bounds.size.height);

glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity(); 

glClearColor(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

glGenTextures(1, &textureName);
glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, textureName);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT, 0, GL_RGBA, videoImageSize.width, videoImageSize.height, 0, GL_YCBCR_422_APPLE, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT_8_8_REV_APPLE, videoTexture);  

glUseProgram(filterProgram);    

glUniform1i(uniforms[UNIFORM_VIDEOFRAME], 0);   

glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, squareVertices);
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, textureVertices);

glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

[super drawInCGLContext:glContext pixelFormat:pixelFormat forLayerTime:interval displayTime:timeStamp];

glDeleteTextures(1, &textureName);
```

This code resides within a CAOpenGLLayer, where the superclass's `-drawInCGLContext:pixelFormat:forLayerTime: displayTime:` simply runs `glFlush()`.

The uniform address is read using code like the following:

```
uniforms[UNIFORM_VIDEOFRAME] = glGetUniformLocation(filterProgram, "videoFrame");
```

As I said, if I comment out the `glUseProgram()` and `glUniform1i()` lines, this textured rectangle draws properly.  Leaving them in leads to a black rectangle being drawn.

What could be preventing my texture uniform from being passed into my fragment shader?

Comment: Does it work if you don't immediately glDeleteTextures?  glDrawArrays is not synchronous...

Comment: @Ben - I've tried it with and without the immediate texture deletion.  That appears to make no difference.  In fact, the original version of this used glTextureRangeAPPLE to just map some memory for the texture and only create it once at the very start of the application.  As I state above, when commenting out the lines activating the shader program, this renders just fine, so I don't believe that's the cause.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure about the GLSL version you're using, but from 1.40 upwards there's the type `sampler2DRect` specifically for accessing non-power-of-two textures. *Might* be what you're looking for, however I don't know how rectangular textures were handled before glsl 1.40.

Comment: Kos is right. The fragment shader says sampler2d, so the shader system will look at GL_TEXTURE_2D binding point to find the texture, not GL_TEXTURE_RECTANGLE_EXT. Those are _different_. So the system never sees the right texture object. As Kos mentions, using either sampler2DRect (if targeted devices support the texture_rectangle extension), or the GL_TEXTURE_2D binding point (if the device supports texture_non_power_of_two). If the hardware supports neither, then you need to upload your frame in a power-of-two texture...

Comment: Bingo.  That's exactly it.  By changing out my uniform to the `sampler2DRect` type, everything displays as it should.  I've been spending too much time with the pre-1.4 GLSL of OpenGL ES 2.0.

Comment: For posterity, I should also add that I needed to change `texture2D()` to `texture2DRect()` in the shader above.